# How to show lines from a text file matching the first five character taking as input?

Tags: c, text-files

I am trying to read text file and compare first five character and print the line if the first five characters match. I have text file like this:

```
03 09 Add this text to file once 
03 09 Add this text to file once 
12 29 Add this text to file once
```

So far, I am able to print the content of text file using following code:

```
while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF) { putchar(c); }
```

I have input argument as `03 09` as date if the first five characters match then I have to print the whole line.

How to do this?

Comment: What specifically do you not know how to do? Many different ways to do what you want. One approach would be to store the contents of each line into a char buffer as a string with `fgets` and then use string functions, such as `strstr`, to do the comparison.

Comment: Do any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this? It takes *text* from file named `input.txt` and *pattern* from standard input. I assumed the maximum length of a line in the file would be 99. You can change it, if you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char inp[100],line[100], temp[6];
    FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    fgets(inp,sizeof(inp),stdin);
    inp[5]=0;

    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),file))
    {
        if(strlen(line)<5) continue;
        strncpy(temp, line, 5);
        temp[5] = 0;
        if(!strcmp(inp,temp)) printf("%s", line);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strncpy(temp, line, 5)` can result in an non-NUL terminated array of characters in `temp`. Missing `temp[5] = '\0';`. And not sure why a `strncpy` to an intermediate buffer is needed anyway and not just `strncmp(line,inp,strlen(inp))`.

Comment: Never use `gets`. It is no longer part of the standard library for security reasons.

Comment: Use `fgets` instead of `gets`. `gets` is too damn dangerous.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks, Done.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for your most valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of approaches you can take. One of the most straight forward is to read the first line in the file, validate it contains at least 5 character, and save it to a reference buffer to compare each subsequent line against. The `strncmp` function will allow you to compare the first `'x'` number of characters in any two strings. Calling `strncmp` on the saved buffer and each new line read and comparing the first 5 characters will tell you if the first five chars of each string are the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXC = 64 }; /* constant for max characters per read */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char s1[MAXC] = "";
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    size_t idx = 0; /* open given file (default: stdin) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line  */
        if (!idx++) {                   /* if 1st store s1 */
            strcpy (s1, buf);
            printf ("%s", s1);
            if (strlen (s1) < 5) {      /* check 5 chars   */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid first line.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            else continue;              /* read next line  */
        }
        if (strncmp (s1, buf, 5) == 0)  /* commpare 1st 5 chars in each line */
            printf ("%s", s1);
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);       /* close file */

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/first5 <../dat/first5.txt
03 09 Add this text to file once
03 09 Add this text to file once
```

**note:** you can add verifications that each line does not exceed the array size by checking that the `strlen` of each line is less than your array size (`-1` to account for the *nul-terminating* character) and that last character in each line is a `newline`. If your line length equals the array size -1 and the last char is not a `newline`, then additional characters remain in that line that should be read and discarded before attempting to check the next line. That is left to you.

Look over the example and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:(I am using the fgets() from the previous reply. Do check if that is correct)

```
while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),file))
{
    if((line[0]=='0')&&(line[1]=='3')&&(line[2]==' ')&&(line[3]=='0')&&(line[4]=='9')){
           print("%s\n",line);
    }
}
```

This code is pretty basic. It does not care how many chars you have in the line but just checks the first 5 to see if they match. If there are any formatting issues then it will not detect it.